# Can a logo be exported as pixel perfect logo without actually making it pixel perfect in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, design-principles, designers

I made this logo without pixel alignment. So I would say I didn't make it pixel perfect. Now when I export it, some edges (most) look blur.

[image]

Can this blur edges be fixed during export somehow? Or you must draw pixel perfect logo?

PS: I have tried pixel perfect things in past and they work quite well. No blur edges.

Comment: Either its been made correctly or its not... Could it be fixed, yes but thats more work than snapping it correctly

Comment: I can't see anything I'd describe as blurry. Are you perhaps referring to the anti-aliasing?

Comment: @BillyKerr not very sure about anti-aliasing. But I would say crisp edges. That's what I mean. And blur means non crisp edges.

Comment: Hmmm . . have you tried selecting the artwork and hitting the "Align Selected Art to Pixel Grid" button?  This may very slightly alter the placement of the paths, but it may be enough for what you want.

Comment: @BillyKerr yeah but I don't want those alterations. So basically it's not possible? You may want to answer my previous question. Because my friend designed same in PowerPoint and it doesn't have blurred edges. Very very strange.

Comment: Sounds like you want to have your cake and eat it.  The choices are clear: either recreate it pixel perfect, or put up with the very slight difference that aligning to the pixel grid will cause, or put up with the anti-aliasing. Which is the worse evil?

Comment: @BillyKerr thing is there's some small text also with this logo, so aligning to pixel will make it look bad since there are many shapes in texts. No? I've seen this in past.

Comment: So, then you could just align some of the artwork, but not the text.

Comment: That might help. I'll try

Comment: @BillyKerr so during export, I should optimize logo for type then?

Comment: Hard to tell. Why not just test it and see which optimization option works best?

Comment: Okay I'll try then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for artwork, especially vector artwork, to be "pixel perfect" the anchors and paths need to rest on the pixel grid properly.

It is **exceptionally** customary for all applications to **not** alter artwork upon export - beyond anti-aliasing or color profiles. In fact, if an application's export feature were to alter the core construction of artwork it would most likely be touted as a very problematic bug or failure in the application. The *entire point* of an application exporting something is to export what you see, not alter its construction.

To this end, no, you can't export "pixel perfect" art if the art isn't initially constructed in the vector application to be pixel perfect. Exporting isn't going to move and shift anchor points to align with the pixel grid.

Comment: Could you please help me by making this line simpler to understand? Little tough to understand for me. It is exceptionally customary for all applications to not alter artwork upon export?

Comment: apps don't change where anchors are.

Comment: During export you mean? For example Illustrator can't change it during export? Or after export other apps can't change it when reusing the exported assets on websites etc.?

Comment: Apps **won't** change it. It would defeat the construction.

Comment: Usually its seen as a good idea to actually do as the expert told the computer to do. Adding too much magic between you and your result may end up causing a lot of unnessesery debugging. That is to say they could not do it but a lot of people would not like that much so its not generally done.

Comment: @Scott I'm really sorry to say I still don't get it. Do you mean: Once we export the logo from illustrator, and then if I use it on my website and my android app, then the browser and android **app** won't change the blurry/antialiasing settings of it?

(Again sorry, my words may seem rude, but I'm not).

Comment: @joojaa would you please clarify? My confusion.

Comment: Pixel perfect from a vector app means the **original** anchors and paths **must** align to the pixel grid. **Nothing** you do will change where those anchors and paths are located originally. Only you, via **manual alteration**, can change where anchors and paths lie. Nothing... not exporting, not displaying, will alter where the **original** anchors and paths were prior to export. (A caveat would be direct **manual** alternation of SVG code.. but it's *still* manual alteration.)

Comment: In short.. if you don't **build** a file as Pixel Perfect, you can't then "force" it to be pixel perfect via some other method.

Comment: @Vikas a programmer could do it. But does most likely not.

Comment: @Scott joojaa got it now. But to test, I just exported a pixel perfect logo of 3000x3000 px and put on a social media creative (creative dimensions: 1080p) in corner. Now at original size, the logo was crisp. But after resizing a lot, some edges became blurry. I can see the same after exporting the creative. Doesn't it contradict that statement that apps can't change alignments?

Comment: If you resize a raster image.. you introduce anti-aliasing. Raster and vector are two very different things. In addition "social media" sites recompress images when you upload them.